# array blowing my mind

Tags: php, arrays

```
$va_fields = array();
 $c = 0;
$field_num = 'field-'.$c;
settype($c,"integer");

while (isset($_POST[$field_num])){
    $posted_field = $_POST[$field_num];
    $va_fields = array( $c => $posted_field);
    echo $c.': ';
    echo '$posted_field: '.$posted_field;
    $c+=1;
    $field_num = 'field-'.$c;

    echo ' <br /> va_fields - c:'.$va_fields[$c];
    echo ' <br /> ';

}
```

For some reason, I cannot for the life of me get the variable $posted_fields into an array.

The values of $posted_field are what I need them to be, so I'm getting the data from the post.  Then I try to store them in an array, and check the array and they aren't there.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  here's my form:

```
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-post.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cpt_field_opts" />
     <!-- some inputs here ... -->
     <?php wp_nonce_field( 'cpt_field_opts', '_wp_nonce' ); ?>
     <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="origin" value="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" />
<?php
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $field){
         ?>
    <input type="textarea" id="field-<?php echo $c; ?>" name="field-<?php echo $c; ?>" value="<?php echo $field; ?>" size="25" /></br>
        <?php
        $c += 1;
        }
?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-post.php">
         <?php wp_nonce_field( 'cpt_field_opts_new', '_wp_nonce_2' ); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cpt_field_opts_new" />
            <input type="hidden" name="origin" value="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
</form>
```

Many people are telling me to rewrite the array as this line:

```
    $va_fields[$c] = $posted_field;
```

Which I have done, but I also started out with that and it still wasn't working

Comment: Instead of `$va_fields = array( $c => $posted_field);` try `$va_fields[$c] = $posted_field;`

Comment: i imagine this is a better way to do *this*, but what *this* is is unclear

Comment: I did want it as a string, just so I could see which value belonged to which variable

Comment: I tried that originally, and it wasn't working, which is why I switched to the expanded syntax

Comment: It's indeed somewhat difficult to make out what you want to accomplish there. Showcase your input form, or `print_r($_POST)`, elaborate how the final output should look. Also consider using array fields right away `<input name="field[]">` to ease this.

Comment: Since you're using a POST array, might have something to do with your form. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: "this" is me trying to put a bunch of values of the same kind in an array, which I then later implode into a string to store.

Comment: in a form if you name a input `name="bob[]"`post will be populated with an array, not clear if this helps but i suspect rewriting the form is part of the solution here. Also "implode into a string to store" suggest possible db issue solvable with normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a bunch of values in `$_POST` with names like "field-0", "field-1", etc, and you're trying to get them into an array:

```
$c = 0;
while (isset($_POST["field-$c"])){

    // This creates a new element in $va_fields with key=$c and value=$_POST["field-$c"]
    $va_fields[$c] = $_POST["field-$c"];

}

var_dump($va_fields); // should show you the array you want
```

But really, it would be easier to just modify your form to use inputs with `name=field[]` instead of numbering them. Then you would already have the array in `$_POST['fields']` without having to do anything.

Comment: This did it, but do you have any idea why mine didn't work?  Also, I tried the array in the name attribute, but I was running into issues with that, too.

Comment: Good call. You figured it out even before the OP posted his form ;-)

Comment: @DavidNoll `$va_fields = array( $c => $posted_field);` was resetting `$va_fields` to a one element array with each iteration of the loop. And then `echo ' <br /> va_fields - c:'.$va_fields[$c];` was not showing what you expected because you had already incremented `$c` to the next index, which did not exist in `$va_fields` at that time.

Comment: But `echo ' <br /> va_fields - c:'.$va_fields[$c];` was outputting nothing at all for that var, and `$va_fields[$c] = $posted_field;` was ouputting nothing and $posted_fields was outputting correct values.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple just iterate the $_POST array

```
<?php
  $va_fields = array();
  $c=0;      
  foreach($_POST as $val){
    echo '$posted_field: '. $val;
    $va_fields[$c] = $val;
  }
  var_dump($va_fields);
?>
```